# Reconnecting a git/Bitbucket repository to the original local drive

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash, atlassian-sourcetree

In my rush to upgrade my PC I had forgotten I had git repositories on a storage drive which I installed in the new PC.

I use Visual Studio to create a build of an open source CMS. I created a repository for the original CMS build using GitBash. I then cloned the original CMS build and created separate repositories so I could work on my production sites modules/themes (one clone for each site).

I would push those module/theme changes to the clones. If necessary, I would push changes to the original CMS repository (which was rare - I left it untouched unless the open source CMS I use had updates; which were then separately pushed to the clones).

I use Bitbucket for the code storage and am using Sourcetree locally to push.

I've tried looking up the answer, but most of what I have read is a bit muddled. Add to this the changes to the Bitbucket and Sourcetree interfaces in the two years since I created these repositories/clones and I feel a bit lost. I'm worried I might make a mistake, so I came here.

How would I go about reconnecting my Bitbucket repositories (both the original CMS, and the clones) to my local drive? Am I going to have to use GitBash, or can I do this through the Sourcetree interface? And how exactly?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I made a mistake. The original CMS was not pushed to Bitbucket. It just was created on my local drive and then the clones were made from there. How do I reconnect the local clones to that original CMS repository using GitBash?

Comment: You may reconnect a Git repo anytime by simply cloning that Git repo to your local drive.  Not sure about your CMS stuff.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So just basically clone it back and let it "overwrite"?

Comment: I don't know if you also have local work which you haven't synched.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I made a mistake. Please see my EDIT. The original CMS was local only, and that's what was used to create the clones.